# PHP Linux safe mode capable file check

Tags: php, linux, file, bootstrapping

I have a simple check in my bootstrap which should check if a directory is writable.

I do it currently with the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

But as stated in the documentation:

> Keep in mind that PHP may be accessing the file as the user id that the web server runs as (often 'nobody'). Safe mode limitations are not taken into account.

It ignores the case when Linux falls into safe mode, which happened to us 1 month ago, the function returned true, even though the file write was not possible, because it ignores the safe mode (where most of the file system get the none owner status)

How can I handle that safe mode correctly and let my scripts die without making a new file on every check (would make insane performance problems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [stat()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stat.php) function or [fileperms()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php) function like this

```
function isWritable($file) {
    $perms = fileperms($file);
    if (is_writable($file) 
      || ($perms & 0x0080)  // owner writable
      || ($perms & 0x0010)  // group writable
      || ($perms & 0x0002)) // world writable
        return true;
}
```